# How to get google analytics to show correct active page on SPA using gtag.js?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm new to Google Analytics and so I've gone ahead and added the `gtag.js` code to my HTML page header and it works great for initial page load. However, I use React and react-router to dynamically change URL and Google Analytics is not picking up the change in active page or new hits when a URL change happens from my SPA.

Answers I've found are for `ga.js` instead of `gtag.js`. I've tried to adapt [Google's documentation suggestion here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/single-page-applications) with the URL listener in other answers to fit my need.. but although the code is running on dynamic page load, nothing is being sent to GA.

```
window.gtag && history.listen((location)=>{
    console.log('>>>', location.pathname)
    gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {'page_path': location.pathname});
    // window.ga('set', 'page', location.pathname);  //--> this would have worked with ga.js
    // window.ga('send', 'pageview', location.pathname);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be on the Google Tag Manager side. Firing an event as shown in the GTM documentation I linked will not do any good if there is no Trigger on the GTM side listening to this event, and a Tag listening to that Trigger.

so the step are:

1. Hook up the app to Google Tag Manager
2. create a trigger in Google Tag Manager listening to the `VirtualPageview` event
3. Create a Tag listening to the Trigger created in step 2, this tag is a Google Analytics tag
4. Now all that needs to happen is for the code to fire off the `VirtualPageview` event. This is done as shown below

--

```
export function virtualPageviewOnRouteChange(history){
    let previousPathname = null
    window.gtag && history.listen((location)=>{
        if(previousPathname != location.pathname){
            previousPathname = location.pathname;
            gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {'page_path':location.pathname});
            dataLayer.push({
                'event':'VirtualPageview',
                'virtualPageURL':location.pathname,
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this could be a React issue. Consider checking this thread:
[React router 4 history.listen never fires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44095744/react-router-4-history-listen-never-fires)

Comment: I actually figured it out. I will post the answer. history.listen has fired it was GA that wasn't firing, but it turns out the solution is simple and handled outside of the code (from GTM).

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention that you're firing the things with GTM.  I suppose you don't need ```gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {'page_path':location.pathname});``` then, ```dataLayer.push()``` will be enough to trigger tag.

Comment: BTW GTM has built-it history change listener so you don't have to make dataLayer.push from the code

Comment: Interesting, any chance you have a link about this for reference?

Comment: Simo has a comprehensive overview https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/google-tag-manager-history-listener/