# How to get Google Analytics to work with React

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-router, use-effect

I'm trying to track each page but google only registers a view each time I click the refresh button. Not when iv'e routed to a new path. Anyone got an Idea on how to make this work?

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import OurWork from "./ourWork/ourWork"
import Home from "./home/Home"
import Packages from "./packages/Packages"
import Contacts from "./contact/Contact"
import ReactGA from 'react-ga'
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
const Routes = () => {
    const {
        ContactPage
    } = Contacts();
    const history = createHistory()
    history.listen(location => {
        ReactGA.set({ page: location.pathname });
        ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname);
    });
    useEffect(() => {
         ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search)
     }, [history])
    return(
        <BrowserRouter history={history}>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Home} /> 
                <Route path="/ourwork" exact component={OurWork} /> 
                <Route path="/packages" exact component={Packages} /> 
                <Route path="/Contact" exact component={ContactPage} /> 
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
export default Routes;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the same issue  which is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44095744/react-router-4-history-listen-never-fires).  Try to change `<BrowserRouter  history={history}>` to `<Router history={history}>` and import `Router` from the `"react-router-dom"`, like this:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import { Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import OurWork from "./ourWork/ourWork"
import Home from "./home/Home"
import Packages from "./packages/Packages"
import Contacts from "./contact/Contact"
import ReactGA from 'react-ga'
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
const Routes = () => {
    const {
        ContactPage
    } = Contacts();
    const history = createHistory()
    history.listen(location => {
        ReactGA.set({ page: location.pathname });
        ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname);
    });
    useEffect(() => {
         ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search)
     }, [history])
    return(
        <Router history={history}>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Home} /> 
                <Route path="/ourwork" exact component={OurWork} /> 
                <Route path="/packages" exact component={Packages} /> 
                <Route path="/Contact" exact component={ContactPage} /> 
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
}
export default Routes;
```